# For similarity of matrices, if A and B are similar, are $A = P^{-1}BP$ and $A = PBP^{-1}$ equivalent?

Tags: matrices

For similarity of matrices, if A and B are similar, are $A = P^{-1}BP$ and $A = PBP^{-1}$ equivalent?

I know that matrix multiplication is not commutative, but it seems to me that it is in this specific case?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please clarify this.

Comment: It's not the same $P$ in the two cases. But apart from that, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you set $P=Q^{-1}$, then we see

$$A=P^{-1}AP=(Q^{-1})^{-1}BQ^{-1}=QBQ^{-1}$$

So yes, they're equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. Being sure is pretty important in mathematics ;)