# Matrix Congruence: Are $B = P^TAP$ and $B = PAP^T$ equivalent?

Tags: matrices, transpose

I know that matrix multiplication is not commutative, but if $B = P^TAP$, then is $B = PAP^T$? In the same way that, if A and B are similar, then $A = P^{-1}BP$ and $A = PBP^{-1}$ are equivalent.

I would appreciate it if someone can please take the time to confirm.

Comment: Both is wrong in general.

Comment: If $P$ are symmetric the first equation is trivially true.

Comment: Sorry, but I phrased it incorrectly. I have edited it now.

Comment: What is your definition of equivalence?

Comment: @Hans I meant are they the same ($=$).

Comment: They are two different but legitimate notions and you are confusing them. See my conversation with José Carlos Santos on this very topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If$$P=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix},$$then$$P^T.A.P=\begin{pmatrix}13 & 18 \\ 20 & 28\end{pmatrix}\text{, whereas }P.A.P^T=\begin{pmatrix}7 & 15 \\ 17 & 37\end{pmatrix}.$$And it is false with inverses intead of transposes, too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the transpose case is different from the inverse matrix case for similar matrices?

Comment: $A=P^{-1}AP=(Q^{-1})^{-1}BQ^{-1}=QBQ^{-1}$? See my question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2703060/for-similarity-of-matrices-if-a-and-b-are-similar-are-a-p-1bp-and-a

Comment: @ThePointer My remark about the inverse concerned your original question, not the edited one.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. So what about my edited question? Is it incorrect for the transpose and correct for the inverse?

Comment: @ThePointer Yes. In general, it is not true that $P^T.A.P=P.A.P^T$, but it is true that $P^{-1}.A.P$ and $P.A.P^{-1}$ are equivalent.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the assistance.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: What is your definition of being equivalent? You do not mean it to be "equal" but similar, right? If you mean they are similar, then it is trivially true as $P^{-1}AP= (P^2)^{-1}(PAP^{-1})P^2$.

Comment: @Hans I know that it is trivial.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: No disrespect is intended. My point is rather I am not familiar with the nomenclature "equivalence" for matrices. I just checked the wikipedia definition of it. The OP seems to be confusing this notion with "equal".

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: The OP's answer to my question above just confirmed my suspicion.

Comment: @Hans I wasn't aware that they meant different things in this case. I only meant "similar" in the inverse example (see my other question), but I said "equivalent" in the sense that they are equal to each other. Sorry for any confusion. Either way, José's answered my question.

Comment: @ThePointer I put an example as an answer, of the type you will most commonly see.

Comment: @ThePointer: Words matter in mathematics. What Jose said would be false if you change one word into another.

Answer (score 1):

This is most important for symmetric matrices. What I do is, for the usual case of congruence with a diagonal matrix, is solve $P^T HP = D,$ then $Q = P^{-1} $  solves $Q^T D Q = H.$ Note that the actual eigenvalues of $H$ are irrational, roots of $x^3 - 12x^2 + x + 1.$ Also, $P$ is NOT orthogonal. The diagonal entries of $D$ are subject to [Sylvester's Law of Inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia) .

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & 4 & 5 \\ 
3 & 5 & 7 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 3 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & 4 & 5 \\ 
3 & 5 & 7 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 3 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
3 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & 4 & 5 \\ 
3 & 5 & 7 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$